# migrate HTML based knowledge base to MediaWiki

Tags: html, mediawiki, migration

In our company we have a large "Knowledge Base" in HTML form so on a general website. I have been implementing a MediaWiki based system as it is faster cleaner and want to allow all users ability to edit and add.

I was curious if there is an "Easy" way to migrate the HTML knowledge base into Wiki form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a tool like [Wiky](http://goessner.net/download/prj/wiky/) to convert HTML to Wiki markup.

Comment: I'm also trying to find a batch converter, but so far I've been unsuccessful.